# I' m trying to get a responsive title + columns with images

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, frontend

I'm new to this and this is the first web page I'm trying to create. By far I managed to create 3 columns and make them responsive. But the `<h2>` + `<p>` are bothering me. I'm trying to push them above the images when displayed on smartphone/tablet screens.

What should I use?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


.hero-image {
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url(images/sanGalgano.jpg);  
  height: 70%; 
  text-align: center;  
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}


.hero-text {
  font-family: 'Bungee Outline', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 43%;
  left: 56%;
  width: 45%;
}

                                          /* 3 circles panel */
.container {
  background-color: #1F3740;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 25rem;
  min-width: 18rem;
  margin: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box.description {
  margin-top: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #d4af37;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: #A0C9D9;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

                                          /* 3 columns panel */
.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  flex: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 30%;
}

.descrizione {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

.descrizione p {
  color: #1F3740;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Francesco <br> Gallo <br> Fotografo</h1>
    <div>
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo2.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="images/torta.png">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="images/bacio.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="images/amiche.png">
  </div>
  <div class="box description">
    <h2>Per i vostri momenti speciali</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>consectetur adipisicing elit.<br> Similique molestias hic velit,<br> ipsum facere nemo minus distinctio <br> est quidem neque.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="descrizione">
    <h2>Ciao, sono Francesco!</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>consectetur adipisicing elit.<br> Similique molestias hic velit,<br> ipsum facere nemo minus distinctio <br> est quidem neque.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/torta.png">
    <img src="images/abbraccio.png">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/vestito.png">
    <img src="images/amiche.png">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/bacio.jpg">
    <img src="images/bolle3.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Also, we really want to see your html. thanks.

Comment: You have missed HTML code, please put it there.

Comment: Sorry guys...don't know why it didn't upload html. Now it's up

Comment: Hello! Can you put some kind a link for your code so that we could preview better. Because when I want to see your code I copied your HTML and CSS to codepen but the images not loaded. So I couldn't preview clearly and I couldn't find a solution.